# Does Spring's @Lazy work when applied to a FactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, factory, lazy-initialization

```
@Component
@Lazy
public class MyFactory implements FactoryBean<MyClass> {
  @Override
  public FeatureStatusProvider getObject() throws Exception {
    return new MyClass();
  }
  @Override
  public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return MyClass.class;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Does the `@Lazy` actually do anything when applied to a FactoryBean?  I'm trying to use this pattern but I keep seeing Spring beans being initialized that aren't being used anywhere, which shouldn't happen when they're configured to be lazy.

Comment: For my understanding: Is the purpose of the factory to construct heavy costly objects? If so in this case a `@Lazy` would make no sense IMHO. As far is I know  `@Lazy`  for Beans is preferred in contrast to the factory

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct.  FactoryBean can be used to construct a bean of a class that you don't own that requires configuration.  For example, we use FactoryBean to create an Apache HTTP Client bean as well as beans for some of the AWS clients.  However, some of these AWS clients aren't used in some of our environments, so with `@Lazy` on the FactoryBean I'd expect those unused clients not to get initialized.  I think this is a perfectly reasonable use for `@Lazy` in conjunction with FactoryBean.

Comment: Interface to be implemented by objects used within a BeanFactory which are themselves factories. If a bean implements this interface, it is used as a factory for an object to expose, not directly as a bean instance that will be exposed itself.

Based on the documentation the FactoryBean is not handled as a Bean itself and maybe therefore Lazy does not work. Have you tried to define a Bean of MyFactory and annotate that bean Definition with Lazy?